# Ошибка при использовании self.request (NameError)

Tags: python, django

У меня есть **view класс** который отслеживает метод запроса(через self.request.method), однако Python ругается на этот код и выбрасывает ошибку.

Возможно, нужно унаследовать переменную `request` через метод `super` из наследуемого класса `DetailView` в методе  `__init__` но как это сделать я не понять и найти в интернете.

> Ошибка:
>   [image: NameError: name 'self' is not defined]

***Упрощенный view.py (только класс):***

```
class ParticularBook(DetailView):
    message = ''

    template_name = 'bookapp/book_info.html'
    context_object_name = 'book'

    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        create_comment(self.request, ParticularBook())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_author'] = Autor.objects.get(author_full_name=self.get_object().book_autor)
        context['message'] = self.message

        return context

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Book, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

    def set_message(self, msg):
        self.message = msg
```

Comment: учите питон...(

Comment: это очень полезный совет, спасибо!

Comment: уберите self
оставьте просто if request.method == 'POST':

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в особенности логики классов в python - весь код, который должен выполняться, обязан находится в методах, реализованных внутри конкретного класса, в данном случае класс `ParticularBook`, остается понять как сделать такой метод, что-бы при обработки url post запроса он выполнялся.

На помощь приходит метод `post` который можно несложно реализовать( а еще применяются такие методы как `get`, `head` и т.д.). Также, стоит уточнить откуда берется вообще этот `post` и почему. Дело в том что все, так называемые **class-based отображения**, наследуют главный, родительский класс именуемый [View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View) именно благодаря ему можно реализовывать функционал, подобный данному случаю. (см. [dispatch](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch))

Ну, собственно говоря вот измененный класс до правильного состояния:

```
class ParticularBook(DetailView):
    message = ''
    template_name = 'bookapp/book_info.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_author'] = Autor.objects.get(author_full_name=self.get_object().book_autor)
        context['message'] = self.message

        return context

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Book, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))

    def set_message(self, msg):
        self.message = msg

    def post(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
        self.message = create_comment(request, self.get_object())

        # context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context = {}
        context['book_author'] = Autor.objects.get(author_full_name=self.get_object().book_autor)
        context['message'] = self.message
        context['book'] = self.get_object()

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```